# Adding each value of an array to a ListObject as a new row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to expand my knowledge of VBA with just testing odd bits of code and deconstructing how it works.

I'm trying to get better at using arrays and understand them a bit more as I think I'll have quite a lot of practical use for them but I'm now getting stuck when trying to use it in conjunction with a ListObject.

I've created the below macro. It successfully fills the array and then puts the content into a worksheet.

However, the problem I am having is that I want to add values to an array and then add those values into a table (list objects) while retaining the existing data in there. At the moment, this just adds the data to the top of table and overrides any existing content. I've tried using many variations of adding a list row which does work, but, it only puts the first value in the array in the table instead of the entire thing.

I want to create a new row, add the data, for each piece of data also set another value for a column in that row and then carry on.

For example, I want the code to do the following:

```
Search for criteria in Table named PRODUCT

Criteria = "Monthly"

Add all the items in column 3 to an array

Put the content of the array in another table called TRACKER. 
For every record put in, set the column called Job Type to STANDARD.
```

So far, this is what I have done below. It's a static array so that it's easier for me to work with while I'm figuring it out, however, in practice I will get the contents of the array from the Worksheet by filtering a listobject and then adding all the values in column 3 to the array.

```
Sub ArrayExercise_3()
Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrTable As ListObject
Dim arrRow As ListRow

Set arrTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Array2").ListObjects("Table7")
Set arrRow = arrTable.ListRows.Add

myArray(1) = 10
myArray(2) = 20
myArray(3) = 30
myArray(4) = 40
myArray(5) = 50

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    arrTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1) = myArray(i)
    arrTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2) = "TEST"
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

I avoid using `ListObject.DataBodyRange` when adding rows.  It the table has no rows then `ListObject.DataBodyRange = Nothing`.  It's much simpler to use `ListObject.ListRows.Add.Range` which will always return a Range Object.

```
Sub Demo()

    Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Integer
    myArray(1) = 10
    myArray(2) = 20
    myArray(3) = 30
    myArray(4) = 40
    myArray(5) = 50

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    rowCount = tbl.ListRows.Count
    tbl.ListRows.Add.Range.Resize(UBound(myArray) + 1, 1).Value = myArray

End Sub
```

Comment: reasonable solution. Just a suggestion to you for making this answer best for the documenting's purpose. The example you used is for the 1-Dimensional array and requesting you to also put another example for 2-D or Tabular array! That way, everything will be covered.

Comment: @KamalBharakhda thanks for the upvote. Appending a 2D arrays are a little trickier with ListObjects because we need to hide/reshow the total row when applicable.   I wanted to keep the answer simple.

Comment: How would you add to a specified column of a table that has more than one column?

Comment: @MichaelH do you want to add a dingle value or an array of values to span over multiple rows of the target column?

Comment: @MichaelH `tbl.ListRows.Add.Range.Resize(UBound(myArray) + 1, 1).Columns(tbl.ListColumns("Units").Index).Value = myArray` and `tbl.ListRows.Add.Range.Columns(tbl.ListColumns("Units").Value = 10`.  In practice, I would set a range variable to the newly added row(s).  E.g. `Set Target = tbl.ListRows.Add`

Comment: I have several 1d arrays that I want to drop in a table. I solved it like this now for one column/array: `Range("TableX[ColumnA]").Resize(UBound(ArrayA) + 1) = Application.Transpose(ArrayA)`

Comment: @MichaelH I see what you mean.  That works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it thus. You need to add a new row for each array element so put it inside the loop. I suspect you can do this without a loop at all though.

```
Sub ArrayExercise_3()
Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrTable As ListObject
Dim arrRow As ListRow

Set arrTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Array2").ListObjects("Table7")

myArray(1) = 10
myArray(2) = 20
myArray(3) = 30
myArray(4) = 40
myArray(5) = 50

For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    arrTable.ListRows.Add
    With arrTable.DataBodyRange
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Value = myArray(i)
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2) = "TEST"
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding rows inside your loop, like this:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    Set arrRow = arrTable.ListRows.Add
    arrRow.Range(1, 1) = myArray(i)
    arrRow.Range(1, 2) = "TEST"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should move the expansion of the ListObject inside the loop, so that a new row is inserted for each array element.

Second, the indexing of the Array and the ListObject is different.

Third, if you write UBound, it's better to write LBound, too.

```
Sub ArrayExercise_3()
    Dim myArray(1 To 5) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arrTable As ListObject
    Dim arrRow As ListRow

    Set arrTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Array2").ListObjects("Table7")

    myArray(1) = 10
    myArray(2) = 20
    myArray(3) = 30
    myArray(4) = 40
    myArray(5) = 50

    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Set arrRow = arrTable.ListRows.Add
        arrTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(arrTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1).Value = myArray(i)
        arrTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(arrTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 2).Value = "TEST"
    Next i

End Sub
```

I did not test the above code but it should work, or at least show the idea. It is not optimized for speed (inserting all the values at the same time must be quicker) but follows the logic of the original code.